# Djangochannelsrestframework custom action doesn't work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I want to create custom action like in documentation but it answer that Method doesn't allow

 Documentation: https://pypi.org/project/djangochannelsrestframework/
"Adding Custom actions" block

other websocket urls worked correctly

My source code:

consumers.py:

```
from games.models import GameLaunchers, GamesCategories, Games, Tournires
from news.models import News
from games.serializers import GamesCategoriesSerializer, GameLaunchersSerializer, GameSerializer, TourniresSerializer
from news.serializers import NewsListSerializer
from market.models import MarketCategory, MarketProductsType, MarketProducts, MarketOrders
from market.serializers import MarketCategoriesSerializer, MarketProductsTypeSerializer, MarketProductsSerializer, MarketOrdersListSerializer
from django.core import serializers

from djangochannelsrestframework.settings import api_settings
from django.http import Http404

from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.consumers import AsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.decorators import action
from djangochannelsrestframework.mixins import (
    ListModelMixin,
    RetrieveModelMixin,
    PatchModelMixin,
    UpdateModelMixin,
    CreateModelMixin,
    DeleteModelMixin,
    PaginatedModelListMixin
)

class GamesLaunchersAddConsumer(
    CreateModelMixin,
    GenericAsyncAPIConsumer,
):
    serializer_class = GameLaunchersSerializer

class GameLaunchersConsumers(GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
    queryset = GameLaunchers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameLaunchersSerializer
    
    @action
    async def send_email(self, request_id, some=None, **kwargs):
        # do something async
        return {'response_with': 'some message'}, 200
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from socketapp import consumers
# from socketapp.views import GamesViewSet
from django.urls import re_path
from djangochannelsrestframework.consumers import view_as_consumer
# from djangochannelsrestframework.consumers import view_as_consumer
# from games.views import GameLaunchersAddView, GameLaunchersView

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/games/launchers/add',
            consumers.GamesLaunchersAddConsumer.as_asgi()),
    re_path(r'ws/games/launchers', consumers.GameLaunchersConsumers.as_asgi()),
]
```

Sending message:

```
{
    "action": "send_email",
    "request_id": 42,
    "some": "value passed as keyword argument to action"
}
```

I got this error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Method \"send_email\" not allowed."
    ],
    "data": null,
    "action": "send_email",
    "response_status": 405,
    "request_id": 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

{
"action": "send_email",
"request_id": 42,
"some": "value passed as keyword argument to action"
}

to this

{
action: "send_email",
request_id: 42,
some: "value passed as keyword argument to action"
}